# New Design Patterns

Tags: uml, design-patterns

is there any new design patterns available other than the patterns covered by GoF book and Head First Design Patterns? Have any one of you used your own design patterns in your projects? Please let me know. if possible give some UML Diagrams. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yeah... there are plenty. Some of them are heavily domain dependent though. Patterns in GoF book are sort of most basic and common ones.

Comment: This should be tagged as Community Wiki.

Comment: @fredley: how to tag this as Community Wiki now?

Comment: Edit your post, and on the lower-right hand side there will be a checkbox for Community Wiki.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you come across the concept of [Anti-Patterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern) yet?  I came across these in the book "AntiPatterns: Refactoring Software, Architectures, and Projects in Crisis" - which I feel is a great read (note: this is a personal recommendation).  This book reviews commonly identified mistakes in software projects and then attempts to provide a resolution, quite often using a GoF pattern.  Interestingly many of the anti-patterns seem to originate in a design pattern being incorrectly applied.

Answer (score 4):

Some of the very best books in my never-ending quest to learn patterns:

- [Gang of Four](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633612)
- [Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321127420)
- [Pattern-Oriented Software Architecture I](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471958697)
- [Pattern-Oriented Software Architecture II](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471606952)
- [Pattern Languages of Program Design 1-5](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Dstripbooks&field-keywords=Pattern+Languages+of+Program+Design&x=0&y=0)
- [AntiPatterns: Refactoring Software, Architectures, and Projects in Crisis](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471197130)
- [The Pattern Almanac](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201615673)

Answer (score 2):

The "sequel" to the GoF book is [Pattern Hatching](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201432935) by John Vlissides. It does not publish really new patterns, but variations of some included in the original GoF book. Its great value is rather in that it shows the thought and design process involved in applying the patterns.

Although this is not an answer to your question in the strict sense, there are also lots of other kinds of patterns relevant to our field:

- [Analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_analysis_pattern)
- [Architectural](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Architectural_pattern_%28computer_science%29)
- [Reengineering](http://scg.unibe.ch/download/oorp/)

Answer (score 1):

I'm quite sure there were Design Patterns before GoF was written that ended up not covered in GoF.  And there have been many created since.

It was from the start just a catalog of some of the most common patterns, and was never exhaustive, nor did it claim to be.